# laravel passport cannot install

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

i am using laravel 7.x version. i want to install laravel passport. but i have a error when i enter **composer require laravel/passport**.
*
Using version ^8.1 for laravel/framework
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.1.0
> - laravel/ui v2.4.0 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.1], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
> - laravel/ui v2.4.0 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.1], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
> - laravel/ui v2.4.0 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.1], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v7.28.1].
> - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.16.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.16.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.18.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.19.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.19.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.21.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.24.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.25.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.26.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.26.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.27.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.28.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.28.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
> - Installation request for laravel/framework ^8.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v8.1.0].
> - Installation request for laravel/ui (locked at v2.4.0, required as ^2.1) -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v2.4.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
*

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/master/UPGRADE.md  try this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The latest version `v10.0` of `laravel/passport` only supports Laravel 8.x.

If you are using Laravel 7.x you have to use version `v9.x`. So do this instead:

```sh
composer require laravel/passport "^9.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try this! It worked for me*

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.*
composer require laravel/passport=~4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run version specific.
Laravel - 8
I deleted composer.lock, update composer.json with passport 10.0
executed
sudo composer require laravel/passport "^10.0"

Comment: Hello Nilesh, it is generally not a good idea to delete the composer.lock file since it could cause an unwanted update to all packages. (although minor updates shouldn't break things, in some cases they do) however, suggesting the `composer require` command was correct, would you mind editing your answer to include that within a preformatted block? (using ``` of course).